# Interfaces in Lua (mocking dependencies)

Tags: java, lua, interface, mocking

**Preamble**

I am writing Lua code to control virtual devices attached to a virtual computer. I do not have control over the "component" library/dependency.

```lua
-- Component is used to access other devices which are attached to the computer on which this is running
local component = require "component"

-- ...

-- ge_terminal is a device which is connected. 
-- Said device is found when the computer starts up
-- So the ge_terminal field/property is not hard-coded, but added at runtime
component.ge_terminal.get_heat()
```

Such calls are very common in my program. My issue is that I do not have access to the external component to which `component.ge_terminal` refers within my development/testing environment.

**The Question**

I would like to know how to abstract calls to external components/devices to so that I can test the business-logic without access said external components/devices.

**Solutions in other languages**

In other languages such as Java or C#, this might be achieved using an interface, or by mocking the external dependency during testing. I would ideally like to find a solution which does not involve additional libraries (which I  do know exist for mocking in Lua).

```java
interface IComponentManager {
    String getProperty(String name) { ... }
}

interface IDevice {
    String getProperty(String name) { ... }
}

// By abstracting how components are accessed, the production versions can be replaced with mock versions.
// The production version calls the live equivalent of "component.ge_terminal" to return the real device.
// The mock version returns custom IDevices which can be configured for testing.
IComponentManager manager = new ProductionComponentManager();
IComponentManager manager = new MockComponentManager();

IDevice device = manager.getComponent("ge_terminal");
String heat = device.getProperty("heat");
```

(I am aware that this is not prime Java code, but it's just for demonstration)

Comment: Why do you need an interface? If in Java/C# IComponentManager/IDevice are classes, don't you have a way to mock them?

Comment: I'm just using Java/C# to demonstrate what I'd like to do (detaching functionality from implementation using an interface, or as you say by mocking for testing), but I have to write this program in Lua.

Comment: I've now updated the question to clarify this @shingo

Comment: Lua is not strongly typed language. In a strongly typed language you need interfaces because you HAVE TO defined the type of parameters and return values, number of parameters before you can use them. But in lua, it's unrestricted, you can even replace the whole `component` if you wish to. Lua doesn't care what `component` is. You just need to know the name of fields and methods.

Comment: So @shingo would the best practise be to make another module with the functions implemented that I want?

Comment: Yes, implement what you want.